# Writing to hdfs retrieve errors

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am using spark , when I tried writing a stream to local disk - worked excellent:

```
logs.foreachRDD((rdd,time)=>rdd.saveAsTextFile("c://tmp/rotman" +  time.milliseconds.toString))
```

Yet, trying to write to hdfs retrieved errors.
when I create file directly to `hdfs` with `"hdfs dfs -put test1 /tmp"` it works fine, so there is no datanode problem.

```
 logs.foreachRDD((rdd,time)=>rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://server1:8020/user/kafka/count" +  time.milliseconds.toString))
```

> 17/06/23 16:42:39 WARN DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
>       org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File
>
> /user/kafka/count1498225335000/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201706231642_0022_m_000000_22/part-00000
>   could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). 
>   There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this
>   operation.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you set your Spark configuration ?

Comment: How many nodes do you have in your HDFS? If you have more than 1 do check its settings for replication factor.

Comment: Hi,
1) Spark config is :     
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaWordCount").setMaster("local[2]")
2) I am using only 1 node ( cloudera quickstart which I loaded to the cloud)
   and I can work with file with HDFS DFS commands.
what am I missing here?